# heading should not repeat while looping xml nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml data:

```
<data>
<item column="left" value="1" />
<item column="left" value="2" />
<item column="right" value="3" />
<item column="left" value="4" />
<item column="right" value="5" />
<item column="right" value="6" />
<item column="right" value="7" />
<item column="left" value="8" />
<item column="right" value="9" />
<item column="right" value="10" />
</data>
```

I want to print a heading `DATA` when the column is right, and i need it only once.
Can any one help me out.

Comment: Can you add an example of the exact output you're looking for. Also, anything that you've already tried?

Comment: Please post some code where you describe what you've done so far.

Comment: i have tried  <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
        <xsl:if test="contains(@column,'right')">
          <xsl:variable name="content">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetSubHeading">
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@column"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          
          <xsl:if test="not(contains($content,'column'))">
            <h2> data</h2>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*[item[@column='right']]">
  <Heading>Data</Heading>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <item column="left" value="1" />
    <item column="left" value="2" />
    <item column="right" value="3" />
    <item column="left" value="4" />
    <item column="right" value="5" />
    <item column="right" value="6" />
    <item column="right" value="7" />
    <item column="left" value="8" />
    <item column="right" value="9" />
    <item column="right" value="10" />
</data>
```

**produces** (what I *guess* is the wanted result as no wanted result was specified!!!):

```
<Heading>Data</Heading>
<data>
   <item column="left" value="1"/>
   <item column="left" value="2"/>
   <item column="right" value="3"/>
   <item column="left" value="4"/>
   <item column="right" value="5"/>
   <item column="right" value="6"/>
   <item column="right" value="7"/>
   <item column="left" value="8"/>
   <item column="right" value="9"/>
   <item column="right" value="10"/>
</data>
```

**If you want to lose the flexibility of using an identity rule, then the above transformation can be shortened to this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*" name="top">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*[item[@column='right']]">
  <Heading>Data</Heading>
  <xsl:call-template name="top"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```